# Converting generators to lists overwrites the values in Python

Tags: python

I have this piece of code in Python 3.5 that implements generators for  batching of potentially large buffered data:

```
def batched_data(data, size=20):                             
    batch = []  
    for d in data:                                                                                                                                                                                
        batch.append(d)
        if len(batch) == size:
            yield batch
            batch.clear()
    yield batch

def buffered_data(data, bufminsize=10, bufmaxsize=20): 
    diter = iter(data)                                                                                            
    buffer = collections.deque(next(diter) for _ in range(bufmaxsize))

    while buffer:                                                                                                                                                                                 
        yield buffer.popleft()
        if len(buffer) < bufminsize:
            buffer.extend(
                next(diter) for _ in range(bufmaxsize - len(buffer)))

def batched_buffered_data(data, bufsize=100, batch=20):      
    yield from batched_data(
        buffered_data(data, bufmaxsize=bufsize, 
                      bufminsize=bufsize - batch),
        size=batch)
```

Now, when I initialize my generator and traverse the batches in a for-loop, everything's fine:

```
In [351]: gen = batched_buffered_data(range(27), bufsize=10, batch=7)
In [352]: for g in gen:
     ...:     print(g)
     ...:
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
[14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
```

However, when I try to use list comprehension or conversion using `list`, this happens:

```
In [353]: gen = batched_buffered_data(range(27), bufsize=10, batch=7)

In [354]: list(gen)
Out[354]: 
[[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
 [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
 [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
 [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]]
```

I am really puzzled about this. There must be some sort of mutable elements involved, but I really don't know what's behind this behavior.

Comment: Changing `batch.clear()` to `batch = []` should fix it.

Comment: It does fix it, but I still don't know exactly why it works.. :-)

Comment: Your generator yields one and the same list multiple times. Then it modifies that list. That's why you get 4 identical lists as output, because they're actually all the same list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `batch.clear()` to `batch = []` should fix it. The problem is the `batch` list, after `clear()`, is still a reference to the one original list. The yield seems to work because it's printing the one list as it appears at the time before mutating the elements on the next `yield`. Setting it to a new list on each `yield` breaks the reference to the previous iteration, so there's no aliasing going on.

If you're still confused, check out this example using your original code with `.clear()`:

```
result = []
gen = batched_buffered_data(range(27), bufsize=10, batch=7)

for g in gen:
     result.append(g)

[print(x) for x in result]
```

Output:

```
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should change `batch.clear()` to `batch = []`.

That is because `.clear()` clear the list and all the variables that point that list become `[]`, on other way `batch = []` just create a new list and assign it to batch